# using bash to analyze svn repository

Tags: bash, svn, shell, repository, increment

I am analyzing software and I am collecting the svn at three different points of the systems life. start, middle and end.
I am currently able to collect the start point of the repository at whatever number I set it to but I need to collect the svn when the repository starts to have data or code in the trunk. would it be best practice to use a while loop, while $ip does not contain... do remove current $ip and get $ip+1

I have the svn url in svn_url.txt and the project name in svn_name.txt.
So i get an output i currently am receiving is:

```
https://ponkout.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ponkout
ponkout
Checked out revision 73.
final revision is: 73
mid revision is: 36
Checked out revision 36.
Checked out revision 1.

#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat svn_url.txt`; do echo $i; done;
for j in `cat svn_name.txt`; do echo $j; done;

svn co $i $j-fp && fpInfo=`svnversion $j-fp`;
echo "final revision is: "$fpInfo;
mpInfo=$((fpInfo/2));
echo "mid revision is: "$mpInfo;
svn co -r$mpInfo $i $j-mp;
ip=$((1));
svn co -r$ip $i $j-ip;
```

Comment: `Latest revision / 2` is a completely inaccurate way to represent the "middle" of anything in a Subversion repository. You may as well say that because an app has 10K lines of code, when you had 5K it was 50% complete.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I am just interested at collecting the data on three points within the systems life. start middle and end. It does not have to be 5000LOC at the mp and 10000LOC at the end. could be 10000LOC in the middle and 5000LOC at the end, showing the system could of been refactored.

Comment: The point I'm making is that based upon other activity in the repository, revision 73 of your code may be *identical* to revision 36 - and thus you have not captured three points, but only two. If you truly want the beginning, the end, and somewhere between, you need to get the **last changed revision** from `svn info` - but even then, `last changed / 2` could represent only one *actual* revision prior to the last one.

Comment: Thank you alroc, I will not just be doing this for the project, ponkout, but for a number of other projects too. I am hoping to get the svn at these points and then get the sloc of each point.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to collect the svn when the repository starts to have data or code in the trunk

Why can you not simply retrieve the log, start at revision 1 and look for the entries where the paths you're interested in were created?

Or better yet, retrieve the log for those specific paths, and look at the very first entry - that will be when it was added.

Comment: i am trying to automate the process of if the revision 1 does not have any code in the trunk then iterate and check the next revision until there is, and then use that as the start point of the system.